# In HTML Table: How To Manage Tables Row Height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

**A Simple Problem:** When table is wider than screen (overflow) and it contains lengthy text in some cells or `<td>`, then the row height will become unnecessary extra.

**Before Overflow :** Normal and Acceptable. http://jsfiddle.net/mg8869ou/1/

**After Overflow :** Problematic after adding cells Only To Right-Side making unnecessary height for whole row and also whole table. http://jsfiddle.net/w1dc380w/4/

All my tables have different length of text in cells, different number of rows and columns. Is there a single solution to manage all my tables(overflow) row height?

**What I think:** use of `whitespace:nowrap` to remove white-space or make every cell single line + force longest cell of every row and column to be square or nearly square will make table compact.

---

**Solutions Not Useful For all rows or columns or tables:**

(1)css `min-width` to columns or cells (2)css `width` to table (3)css `whitespace:nowrap` to table.

Because all cells have different amount of text in it, tables have different width, number of cells, rows & columns. So these CSS leaves useless white-space and unable to make a table compact as possible.

Is there any way to solve this with or without Javascript or any better way what I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No extra white-space solution for you,

In your case this jquery will check every row to , and increase the table width till all rows are nearly equal height.

```
var i = 0,
    j, row, table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
while (row = table.rows[i++]) {
    j = 1000;
    while (row.offsetHeight > 200 && j < 2500) {
        j += 500;
        table.style.width = j + 'px';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JQuery=javascript i hope this is acceptable for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/w1dc380w/8/

```
$( "th,td" ).each(function( index ) {
$( this ).wrapInner( "<div class='wrapper'></div>"); 


});
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

simple, we need divs sometimes... :)

Comment: thanks for trying, but can't you see clearly in 1st, 2nd, 3rd....  columns extra width or white-space?

Comment: @feacco, yes, now i am thinking... and actually, i realized i can't even imagine desired solution. :) For example, what is your idea: how two adjacent cells (let's take cells from first row: with number 6 -> one character, one line, AND cell number 7, with few lines of text) should actually look, next to each other? 'Square look' without some empty space is impossible, right?

Comment: P.S. maybe you actually don't need tables... maybe you are more for structure like this: http://desandro.github.io/masonry/ different widths/heights, minimal empty spaces, and, well... ''almost square look''... that's all i can think of right now... :)

Answer (score 0):

You've categorized this as `javascript`, so I'm going to assume you're okay with using some scripting here. I tried some CSS solutions myself from Google and SO, but unfortunately many were responsive based and/or relied on knowing a fixed width - out of the question.

So I used a **javascript snippet** to loop through all the `<td>` elements, find which one had the greatest height, then use half of that height to make all of the `<td>` look roughly square. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1dc380w/7/)**

```
var greatestHeight = 0;

$('td').each(function(index){
    if($(this).height() > greatestHeight){
        greatestHeight = $(this).height();
    }
});

$('td').css('min-width', (greatestHeight / 2));
```

It's not perfect, and I'd recommend that you qualify this per table if you have more than one table per page (ie, `td.firstTable`), otherwise the logic will run between tables.

Comment: thanks for trying, but can't you see clearly in 1st, 2nd, 3rd....  columns extra width or white-space ?

Comment: @feacco You suggested making all table cells square, though. In doing so, you will naturally have extra whitespace. I'm with nevermind here - you can't have a square look without space around the elements that don't fill that square fully.